# Accessing child window objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to access JavaScript objects in child window, here is my code:

```
var bw = window.open("broadcast.html",'broadcast');
```

And then I'm accessing JS object:

```
bw.childObj.f();
```

The problem is, that JavaScript is probably evaluating too long in child window and `childObj` is sometimes not accessible right after `window.open`. The same issue occures even when I put it in `onload`:

```
$(bw).on('load', function() {
  bw.childObj.f();
}
```

5 of 10 times `childObj` is simply undefined. However, when I do this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  bw.childObj.f();
}, 3000);
```

I always get a result but, of course, that's not the right deterministic solution.

How can I do this synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

You can try listening to `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` events:

```
var bw = window.open("broadcast.html",'broadcast');
bw.addEventListener('load', function(){
    bw.childObj.f();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick.

In your `broadcast.html`, attach a `window.onload` event like this

```
window.onload = function () {
    /* `fn` is not defined in `broadcast.html`, it's defined
       in another html/js file */
    fn(childObj);
}
```

In your another html/js file:

```
var bw = window.open("broadcast.html",'broadcast');
/* we add `fn` function to `bw` object */
bw.fn = function (obj) { obj.f(); }
```